# CodePilot inside SQL Server SSMS

Tags: sql-server, openai-api, github-copilot

As far as I can see the only options currently for copilot/ChatGPT SQL assistance is to generate queries outside of SSMS.

The real power would be within the SSMS, with access to table definitions, SP's etc. I could see this saving me hours of dev time. Anyone know if there's anything on the cards or whether MS allows for external tools to be incorporated into SSMS?

Comment: This is probably the best example I've seen of _lack of research_ my advice to anyone else who is going to post questions about openAI is to ask it first...

Comment: @ChrisSchaller so if you consider this question lack of research, why up-vote it? Down-vote is for lack of research.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, Dale K I appreciate the concern for people posting 101 openAI questions without first researching, however I think you've falsely categorised me :) I'm not using SSDT or Azure Data Studio. I'm using SSMS. I've already read about the support both of these have but nothing on SSMS, hence why I posted.

Comment: To be honest, its not a valid question for this site, its not about programming, its about tools - which is off topic.

Comment: Any add ins like this are likely to be implemented in Azure Data Studio, not SSMS. Or whatever web dev tool exists in Fabric / Synapse

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I ended up using the 'SQL Server (mssql) VSC extension which you can install here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql

To save a bunch of googling here's what I did to get up and running.

1. Install the extension.

[image]

2. Create and save a new *.sql file in your explorer somewhere (the below won't work unless a .sql file has focus

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - select MS SQL: Connect

[image]

3. Paste in the connection string (from your appsettings.json etc) - press enter through everything else if you like.

You should now see your database in the SQL Server tab in the left pne.

[image]

Right click your DB to create a new query.

[image]

Click the green play button to run the query (do not use <kbd>F5</kbd>)

[image]

Not a perfect approach but good enough for some quick SQL debugging and can never remember how to insert a record etc.

Comment: "Not a perfect approach" .... hmmm I think this is a perfect approach. I 99% migrated from SSMS to vs-code 2 years ago and do not miss SSMS

Comment: Thanks for this.  Going to give it a shot.  It's going to be hard to lose the F5 muscle memory.

Answer (score 0):

Only way right now is to get Azure Data Studio and install copilot